# positive lookahead string matching to a symbol

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

I have a string like this `test |firstresult |secondresult |thirdresult`

I'd like the output to be a string with a new line for every `|` available

Expected Output:

`test
|firstresult
|secondresult
|thirdresult`

I've tried using `str.split` but the delimeter is lost. I've also tried `str.split(/(?=|)/)` which doesn't seem to like the `|` symbol.

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: why do you think it doesn't "like" the symbol? Maybe it would work if it was escaped with a backslash?

Comment: To match a literal pipe, escape it. `str.split(/(?=\|)/)` or `str.split(/\s*(?=\|)/)` will work

Comment: thanks, escaping the | worked `str.split(/(?=[|])/)`

Comment: simply replace `(?=\|)` with newline. if its split has to be joined waste of time